# Two interactions are individually signifcant, but not when included together

Tags: logistic, interaction, stata

So I have two interaction terms (ordinal x ordinal--treating each as continuous) I'm trying to test in a logistic regression model. Interaction 1 is significant--but not when Interaction 2 is present. Likewise, interaction 2 is significant--but not when interaction 1 is included. I thus went ahead and tried a 3-way interaction, but it wasn't significant either. Not sure how to interpret this (do I have to choose one 2-way interaction?), so would appreciate some input. See below for screenshots of what I'm referring to.

[image]

Comment: Not a duplicate. That question doesn't ask about interaction terms.

Comment: This is a duplicate. It doesn't matter whether the variables in question are interactions or not. The reason is the same.